# Does flake8 require any installation of my Python project's dependencies?

Tags: python, code-analysis, requirements.txt, flake8

Is Flake8 a pure static code analyser or should I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` first?

Or, is there any use case where Flake8 can use the installed dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

flake8 by itself (with the default plugin set) is a purely static linter and does not rely on your installed application dependencies

there are some plugins which will require dynamic analysis such as `flake8-mypy` or `flake8-isort`

(disclaimer: I am the current maintainer of `flake8`)